# html - How to show input time show M:S.ms (minutes:second.milisecond)?

Tags: javascript, html, time

how i can input time in html?

I want the format for the input is MM:SS.ms.

I want to make time-table like in https://www.olympic.org/pyeongchang-2018/results/en/alpine-skiing/results-men-s-downhill-trno-000100-.htm

```
MM: minutes
SS: second
ms: milisecond
```

This is what i have done so far

```
<style type="text/css">
    #time1, #time2 {
        width: 125px;
    }        
</style>

<form>
    <label for="time1">Result </label>
    <input id="time1" type="text" name="time1">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time1')"> Input Time?
    <br>
    <label for="time2">Result </label>
    <input id="time2" type="text" name="time2">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time2')"> Input Time?

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function enableInputTime(id) {
        var id = document.getElementById(id);
        if(id.type === 'text') {
            id.type = 'time';
            id.step = "0.1";
        } else {
            id.type = 'text';
            id.list = "Options";
        } 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Have a read about: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp /n and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Also have a look at moment.js library that will help with formatting

Comment: @lovemyjob the problem is i should not use any plugin / framework. And i am trying to input not get the value from current datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id=foo name=foo type=time min="0:00" max="120:00">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tz35nqso/

I know HTML5 has an input time element but you would have to drop the millisecond field. Otherwise go with a 3rd party library like the others suggested.

Comment: input type time is for time of the day, not for timespans. Thus max 120:00 has no effect since it only goes from 00 to 23. It's always in 24-hour format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format